# How to change wavwrite and its parameters to audioread in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am working on Speaker Recognition System and trying to record a voice and save in database to recognize later.

```
disp('Recording stopped.');
y1 = getaudiodata(micrecorder);
y = getaudiodata(micrecorder, 'uint8');
if size(y,2)==2
    y=y(:,1);
end
y = double(y);
sound_number = sound_number+1;
data{sound_number,1} = y;
data{sound_number,2} = classe;
data{sound_number,3} = 'Microphone';
data{sound_number,4} = 'Microphone';
st=strcat('u',num2str(sound_number));         %error here
wavwrite(st,y1,samplingfrequency,samplingbits)%error here
save('sound_database.dat','data','sound_number','-append');
msgbox('Sound added to database','Database result','help');
disp('Sound added to database');
```

But I am receiving this error:

> Undefined function or variable '`wavwrite`'.
>   Error in `voicerecognition` (line 66)
>   `wavwrite(y1,samplingfrequency,samplingbits,st)`

I tried to change to `audioread` but I don't know how to change its values.
Note: `st` is used to represent the filename.

Comment: *What* error was received?

Comment: Undefined function or variable 'wavwrite'.

Error in voicerecognition (line 66)
                    wavwrite(y1,samplingfrequency,samplingbits,st)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wavwrite`](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/wavwrite.html) was removed in MATLAB R2015b. You're using a later version and hence the error. The equivalent of `wavwrite` is [`audiowrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiowrite.html), not [`audioread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioread.html).

```
audiowrite(st,y1,samplingfrequency,'BitsPerSample',samplingbits);
```